# EFS CSI driver on EKS Fargate

Tags: amazon-eks, aws-fargate

I am deploying EFS CSI driver on EKS Fargate but getting below error for `efs-csi-controller` deployment

Error:

```
"Pod not supported on Fargate: fields not supported: HostNetwork, invalid SecurityContext fields: Privileged, port contains HostIP or HostPort"
```

Below is the snippet:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: aws-efs-csi-driver
  name: efs-csi-controller
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: efs-csi-controller
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: kustomize
      app.kubernetes.io/name: aws-efs-csi-driver
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: efs-csi-controller
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: kustomize
        app.kubernetes.io/name: aws-efs-csi-driver
    spec:
      containers:
      - args:
        - --endpoint=$(CSI_ENDPOINT)
        - --logtostderr
        - --v=2
        - --delete-access-point-root-dir=false
        env:
        - name: CSI_ENDPOINT
          value: unix:///var/lib/csi/sockets/pluginproxy/csi.sock
        image: 602401143452.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/eks/aws-efs-csi-driver:v1.3.4
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        livenessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 5
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: healthz
          initialDelaySeconds: 10
          periodSeconds: 10
          timeoutSeconds: 3
        name: efs-plugin
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9909
          name: healthz
          protocol: TCP
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/lib/csi/sockets/pluginproxy/
          name: socket-dir
      - args:
        - --csi-address=$(ADDRESS)
        - --v=2
        - --feature-gates=Topology=true
        - --extra-create-metadata
        - --leader-election
        env:
        - name: ADDRESS
          value: /var/lib/csi/sockets/pluginproxy/csi.sock
        image: 602401143452.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/eks/csi-provisioner:v2.1.1
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: csi-provisioner
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/lib/csi/sockets/pluginproxy/
          name: socket-dir
      - args:
        - --csi-address=/csi/csi.sock
        - --health-port=9909
        image: 602401143452.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/eks/livenessprobe:v2.2.0
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: liveness-probe
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /csi
          name: socket-dir
      hostNetwork: true
      nodeSelector:
        kubernetes.io/os: linux
      priorityClassName: system-cluster-critical
      serviceAccountName: efs-csi-controller-sa
      volumes:
      - emptyDir: {}
        name: socket-dir
```

Answer (score 2):

Pod that required `hostNetwork: true` cannot run on Fargate. You need to install the EFS driver on EC2 node group by using a namespace not in the Fargate profile.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue from my end, after many failed attempts... I found the article announcing the feature - https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/08/amazon-ek-on-aws-fargate-now-supports-amazon-efs-file-systems/

It states "AWS Fargate will use the EFS CSI driver to automatically mount an EFS file system requested by a pod running on Fargate, without the need for manual driver installation."

Therefore, we don't need to manually install the EFS CSI driver in EKS Fargate, it is only necessary for EC2 node groups. Also, please note that we can't use dynamic persistent volume provisioning with Fargate nodes, but we can use static provisioning - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/efs-csi.html

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to deploy the EFS controller. Per the [EFS CSI driver documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/efs-csi.html):

`You can't use dynamic persistent volume provisioning with Fargate nodes, but you can use static provisioning` and `You can't use dynamic provisioning with Fargate nodes.`

You can open a roadmap request [here](https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues).